# how to match entity type dynamic from database data in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc, apoc

I want to add relationship.
I used apoc to batch add relationship and read data from mysql tables.
I have to match entity types dynamic from mysql values.

the column value in mysql is like this: `'entity_name/value`'
I have to split it .
so my code is

```
match(p:split(toString(row.from_key),'/')[0]{from_key:split(toString(row.from_key),'/')[1]})
```

and this failed .

I can only use solid patten like `match(p:entity_name{from_key:split(toString(row.from_key),'/')[1]})`
and this worked.

Comment: is there any way to change entity type from database data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
MATCH (p) 
WHERE split(toString(row.from_key),'/')[0] IN labels(p) 
AND p.from_key = split(toString(row.from_key),'/')[1]
```

Comment: my cql patten like this   Match (p1),(p2)  merge on create...on match ...  and how to order my match sentence within two entity?

Comment: what do you mean by order here?

Comment: the full patten in my cql is `CALL apoc.peridoic.iterate('Call apoc.load.jdbc("mysql...","sql...") yield row','cql statment',{batchSize})`.   The cql is combine `match(e1),(e2) Merge (e1)-[r]-(e2) on create set r.perporties on match  set r.perporties`.  Where should I order the where sentence on set both e1 and e2's labels ?

Comment: You can try `match(e1),(e2) WHERE split(toString(r.from_key),'/')[0] IN labels(e1) AND WHERE split(toString(r.from_key),'/')[0] IN labels(e2) Merge (e1)-[r]-(e2) on create set r.perporties on match  set r.perporties` this.